# random integer in Matlab within a range but excluding values

Tags: matlab

I have generated random numbers in MATLAB within a range using the below:

```
N=10000;
n=3000;
c=randperm(N,n);
```

I need another set of random numbers within the same range `1:N` and of the same size `n` but excluding the values in `c`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use again `randperm` excluding the integers of array `c` to crate array `d` with same length `n`:

```
ok = 1:N;
ok(c) = [];
d=ok(randperm(numel(ok),n));
```